# JSoup, if else statement for checking if tag exist

Tags: java, jsoup

The problem I have been facing is that there are 25 elements of 
div class = secondary-attributes in a page, and I am trying get the address tag, but within some of these 25 div elements, the address tag may not exist at all.

Whereas the span class = neighbour will always be there.
I need to get the text out from the address if there is, else I will get the text out from the span class & print out address not exist.

```
    div class="secondary-attributes" 
    <span class="neighbor-str-list"> Mrt </span>
    <address>anything</address>
```

This are the codes that I have tried after searching around but it doesn't get the job done, as it gets the whole site for the address attribute size.

```
     Elements a2 = doc.select("div.secondary-attributes");
     doc.select("div.secondary-attributes>address").size() > 0){
                    System.out.println("exist!");                        
                }
                else{
                    System.out.println("nothing");
```

These are my original codes. But it stops whenever I encounter the div block without the address.

```
Elements a2 = doc.select("div.secondary-attributes");        
for (Element List : a2) {
    System.out.println("Address:"+List.getElementsByTag("address").get(0).text());
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make select on specific element:

```
Elements a2 = doc.select("div.secondary-attributes");             
for (Element e : a2) {                                            
    if (e.select("div.secondary-attributes>address").size() > 0) {
        System.out.println("exist!");                             
    } else {                                                      
        System.out.println("nothing");                            
    }                                                             
}
```

First you select all `divs` with class `secondary-attributes`. Then you loop through every div and for each div you check if address tag exists.